# How to match starting date to the closest ending date in order to get the time difference

Tags: db2

```
SELECT 
  OUT.EMP_ID, 
  OUT.DT_TM "DateTimeOut",  
  IN.DT_TM "DateTimeIn", 
  cast(timestampdiff( 4, char(timestamp(IN.DT_TM) - timestamp(OUT.DT_TM))) as decimal(30,1))/60 "Duration Out" 
FROM ( 
  select  
    e1.EMP_ID,   
    e1.DT_TM    
  from 
    hr.timeout e1   
  WHERE      
    month(e1.DT_TM)=09   
    and year(e1.DT_TM)=2016   
    AND e1.CD='OUT'
) OUT 
LEFT JOIN (  
  select   
    e2.EMP_ID,   
    e2.DT_TM   
  from   
    hr.timeout e2   
  WHERE      
    month(e2.dt_tm)=09   
    and year(e2.dt_tm)=2016   
    AND e2.CD='IN'  
) IN   
on out.EMP_ID=in.EMP_ID
```

Trying to get the closest `DateTimeIn` match with the `DateTimeOut`. 
Currently it repeats the same `DateTimeOut` and `DateTimeIn` multiple times.

Comment: You might want to show some sample data and expected results.

Comment: order by (datetimein - datetimeout ) desc  or something like that...

Answer (score 0):

I think its normal because your table dont have constraint unique on emp_id, dt_tm and cd. But if you want unique result try this :

```
    With Period as (
    select  e1.EMP_ID,  e1.DT_TM  from hr.timeout e1   
    WHERE month(e1.DT_TM)=09 and year(e1.DT_TM)=2016
    )
    Select  distinct OUT.EMP_ID,  IN.DT_TM  as DateTimeIn, OUT.DT_TM as DateTimeOut,
    TIMESTAMPDIFF(2 , CAST(timestamp(IN.DT_TM) - timestamp(ifnull(OUT.DT_TM, current date)) AS CHAR(22)) ) as DurationSecond
    from Period in left outer join Period out 
    on out.EMP_ID=in.EMP_ID and out.CD='OUT' and in.CD='IN'
    order by 1, 2, 3
```

Like you can see, i use timestampdiff with '2' like first parameter for second (you divided by 60), i use ifnull because you do a left outer join (out.DT_TM can be null) and i do a distinct for unique result